# How to align Bootstrap columns in center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working in a design, that requires to align the row items in the center. If I had a pre-defined amount of columns, then it is easy to align them, but I have a dynamic amount of columns and I don't know how to align them. So the content should be like following examples:

```
|----| |----| |----|
|    | |    | |    |
|----| |----| |----|

|----| |----| |----|
|    | |    | |    |
|----| |----| |----|
```

Or

```
|----| |----| |----|
|    | |    | |    |
|----| |----| |----|

    |----| |----|
    |    | |    |
    |----| |----|
```

or

```
|----| |----| |----|
|    | |    | |    |
|----| |----| |----|

       |----|
       |    |
       |----|
```

In my `HTML` I have implement this code:

```
<div class="row row-centered">
    <!-- Loop here to make the dynamic amount of columns -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-centered text-center">
    </div>
    <!-- End the loop here -->
</div>
```

and in my `SASS` I have this code:

```
.row-centered {
    text-align : center;

    .col-centered {
        display      : inline-block;
        float        : none;
        /* reset the text-align */
        text-align   : left;
        /* inline-block space fix */
        margin-right : -4px;
    }
}
```

But this gives me this result:

```
|----| |----|
|    | |    | |----|
|----| |----| |    |
              |----|
|----| |----|
|    | |    | |----|
|----| |----| |    |
              |----|
```

Or

```
|----| |----| 
|    | |    | |----|
|----| |----| |    |
              |----|
           |----|
    |----| |    |
    |    | |----|
    |----|
```

or

```
|----| |----| 
|    | |    | |----|
|----| |----| |    |
              |----|
       |----|
       |    |
       |----|
```

So, is there any other way to achive the same alignment without braking the columns ?

**NOTE:** The rows of item are un-know as well, can be one, two or thousand of rows. I have use up to two lines of items, just for simplicity.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to use the Framework correctly by always ensuring rows equal to 12 columns. Then you won't need to hack thing up your own css.

Comment: @PhillHealey This solution it counts if you have exactly three items per row. But this is not usefull as I like to change the items width for small and medium screens, thus I have to put all the elements in a single row, and in my case it breaks. Anyway, thank you for your help ;) I appreciate it.

Comment: You should still use bootstrap markup. Post a fiddle with some example code.

Comment: It depends on the height of the cols. Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to add `vertical-align:top;` to all of the boxes. This will make them align at the same position.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not :(, I just try it and seems like not work :(

Comment: Do you have an example somewhere?

Comment: OK :) I add vertical-align: top; to the parent element as well and now it works perfectly !! :) Thanks

Comment: Unfortunatelly the project it is an internal project of the company I work for. Anyway thank you :) I will mark your answer as the rignt in a few minutes. Thanks again.

Comment: This really isnt the best way to go about it. Use the bootstrap framework properly by building your columns and layouts with the relevant bootstrap css.

Answer (score 0):

Go with bootstrap 4 and use `card-deck`